# select unique values from union in mysql by MAX(datefield)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in mysql db with same schema but different data and I want to select the record that is the latest based on date field on both the tables.

Table : **FamilyStatement**:

| id | familyId | dateEmailed | amount | statementurl |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2023-01-07 12:17:47 | 45.07 | statement311d7c30.pdf |

Table : **AccountStatement**:

| id | familyId | dateEmailed | amount | statementurl |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2023-08-08 09:10:47 | 5.07 | statement311d111.pdf |

when I execute the following query by doing a union on both the tables and MAX(dateEmailed) I get the correct value returned in the dateemailed column but the query does not brings all the other related fields from that table.

```
SELECT familyid,MAX(dateemailed),amount,statementurl FROM 
(
   SELECT familyid,dateemailed,amount,statementurl  FROM familystatement
   UNION
   SELECT familyid, dateemailed, amount,statementurl FROM accountstatement) a 
GROUP BY familyid ORDER BY familyid
```

**result**

| familyId | dateEmailed | amount | statementurl |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2023-01-07 12:17:477 | 5.07 | statement311d111.pdf |

**expected**

| familyId | dateEmailed | amount | statementurl |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2023-01-07 12:17:477 | 45.07 | statement311d73c30.pdf |

Could you please let me know how I can achieve this result.

Comment: Are you on cheat mode or how are you able to execute your query without either aggregating the amount and the statementurl or adding them to the GROUP BY clause?

Comment: What if both records have the same date? Which other records are in this table? Can there be multiple records having the same familiyId in the tables? You must be much more clear and precise about what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need a `WHERE` clause which will fetch row(s) for the MAX date value. Something like this:

```
select *
from (select familyid, dateemailed, amount, statementurl from familystatement
      union
      select familyid, dateemailed, amount, statementurl from accountstatement)
     )
where datemailed = (select max(datemailed)
                    from (select datemailed from familystatement
                          union
                          select datemailed from accountstatement
                         )
                   );
```

Could be simplified if you used a CTE:

```
with temp as
  (select familyid, dateemailed, amount, statementurl from familystatement
   union
   select familyid, dateemailed, amount, statementurl from accountstatement
  )
select *
from temp
where datemailed = (select max(datemailed) from temp);
```

Code you wrote does return the MAX **date** value from the union, but GROUP BY clause on non-aggregated columns will return wrong result (as you already noticed).

Comment: both versions worked but CTE was lot quicker as there were around 450 records in both the tables .